# Kali Linux login screen does not appear in VMware Workstation 15 Pro

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux, login-screen

I have recently installed Kali Linux on the VMware Workstation Pro, and everything is okay after installation. However, after each restart, it shows the Debian login screen instead of the Kali Login Screen every time (you can see it in [VMware Kali Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Zqx.png)).

Also, I try to input the username and password as "root" and my custom password, but nothing happens.

**VMware Information:**

```
VMware® Workstation 15 Pro
Version: 15.5.0 build-14665864 
Host OS Version: Windows 10, 64-bit  (Build 18362) 10.0.18362
```

**Kali Linux Information:**

```
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 64-bit
Release:    2019.4
Codename:   kali-rolling
Gnome Version: 3.34.1
```

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: Kali recently switch to the Debian kernel.  You are running the most recent version, the version which this switch changed to, what exactly is your question?

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for answering. I know how to install Kali Linux, and I am not a beginner for sure! I have been worked three last years with Kali Linux for different usage, and also I had a complete kali virtual machine in VMware Workstation Pro version 12  for one year. Nevertheless, if you had read the question carefully, as I remarked, I install Kali Linux successfully. I think the problem is with the last version of VMware software or something else.

Comment: Dear @Ramhound, thanks for answering, actually I installed Kali as a VMware virtual machine with an ISO file "kali-linux-2017.2-amd64.iso". After Installing, I use sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade, and sudo apt dist-upgrade commands for updating. So, as you can see in question, I am currently running Kali Linux version 2019.4. But, after each restart of the virtual machine, it is showing a login screen like one that I mentioned in the question. Therefore, I decided to take a snapshot of the kali virtual machine and revert to it each time. Do you have any idea to fix the login screen problem?

Comment: The login screen is supposed to say Debian.

Comment: @hossein abdi You may find Kali Community Support helpful for other Kali-specific issues https://www.kali.org/community/

Comment: @K7AAY Yes, I find the answer in the kali linux forums. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I find the solution in [Kali Community Support](https://www.kali.org/community/). Actually the problem is freezing at login TTY and with [instructions at this link](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?31090-Sovled-install-kali-freeze-at-login-tty1-can-t-start-gui) it can be solved.

> 1. Get in to the root terminal root@kali:~#
> 2. Start internet connection with `service network-manager start` (your eth0 should be ready)
> 3. `apt-get update`
> 4. `apt-get upgrade` (gonna take a while)
> 5. `apt-get dist-upgrade-y && reboot` (in order for the new update, upgrade to take effect you need to reboot)
> 6. boot back into your Linux by the BIOS
> 7. chose recovery options
> 8. let it load, enter password (not Ctr-D)
> 9. start internet connection again: `service network-manager start`
> 10. `uname-a` (check your host name and version of Linux headers)
>       It should say something like:
>
>     > Linux Kali 4.5.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.3-2kali1 (2016-05-09) x86_64 GNU/Linux
>     >     Kali is my host name so it say Kali but it can be vary depend on your set up when install
> 11. `apt-get install linux-headers-$(Kali-r)` ← Kali is my host name, depending on what your host name is type it in, check by cmd : `uname-a`. Some article or post use (`uname-r`) and the results is no location found so the correct way is type in your host name
> 12. `apt-get install nvidia-driver nvidia-kernel-dkms nvidia-xconfig nvidia-settings`
> 13. check if `xorg.conf` file is in the `/etc/x11` folder by typing `nvidia-xconfig`
>       It should say something like
>
>     > Using X configuration file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf".
>     >     Backed up file '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' as '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup'
>     >     New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf'
> 14. Reboot your system by typing `reboot`
> 15. When the Grub boot appears, choose the first boot option `GNU/Linux`
>
> Now it should load you in to GUI mode with nice ration and resolution